Using a LSP server for Python with GObject Introspection bindings
I am writing code that heavily used GObject Introspection, so the code starts with:
import gi
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import GLib
# .. and more of the same

Using the basic LSP-python server (*) with my editor I don't get any meaningful help for these (I do get useful help for regular Python libs, so the LSP works). What should I add and where to have all these libs added?
Bonus points: some of these libraries are in a GI_TYPELIB_PATH extension.
(*) python3-pylsp 1.10.0-1 on Ubuntu 24.04
